# Question about second Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this theorem that says:

If H and K are subgroups of a group G, then $[H:H\cap K]\leq[G:K]$. If $[G:K]$ is finite then $[H:H\cap K]=[G:K]$ if and only if $G=KH.$

And if K is normal, then KH is a subgroup, so we will have $[H:H\cap K] = [G:K]$ and hence $|H|/|H \cap K| = |HK|/|K|$

However, I know that second isomorphism theorem says that if we have an extra condition saying K is a normal subgroup of G. Then we have $H/(H \cap K)$  isomorphic to $HK/K$. And this will mean that $|H|/|H\cap K| = |HK|/|K|$. Why then do we need G = KH?

My question is what are the difference between these two? I find the first theorem redundant?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $HK=KH$ is a subgroup is not sufficient to conclude that $[H:H\cap K]=[G:K]$ as you have written. In that case we can only conclude that $[H:H\cap K]=[HK:K]$, and if $HK\neq G$ this will not be equal to $ [G:K]$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if $G$ is finite then $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ for any two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$. But here $HK$ need not be a subgroup of $G$. If $K$ is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Now if $G = HK$ then $[H : H \cap K] = [G : K].$ On the other hand $[H : H \cap K] = [G : K] \Rightarrow |HK| = |G| \Rightarrow G = HK.$